# Solution to the problem solving minimum number of meeting rooms required to hold all the meetings

Tags: algorithm, go, intervals

Below is the problem statement:

Given a list of intervals representing the start and end time of ‘N’ meetings, find the minimum number of rooms required to hold all the meetings.

Examples:

- **Meetings**: [[1,4], [2,5], [7,9]]
  , **Output**: 2
- **Meetings**: [[1,4], [2,3], [3,6]]
  , **Output**: 2

My Solution using Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    intervals := NewIntervalList([][]int{{12, 13}, {13, 15}, {17, 20}, {13, 14}, {19, 21}, {18, 20}, {12, 13}})
    fmt.Println(MinMeetingRooms(intervals))
}

type Interval struct {
    Start int
    End   int
}

type Intervals []Interval

func NewIntervalList(list [][]int) Intervals {
    var intervals = make(Intervals, 0, len(list))
    for _, v := range list {
        intervals = append(intervals, Interval{Start: v[0], End: v[1]})
    }
    return intervals
}

func MinMeetingRooms(intervals Intervals) int {
    if len(intervals) < 1 {
        return 0
    }
    sort.Slice(intervals, func(a, b int) bool {
        if intervals[a].End == intervals[b].End {
            return intervals[a].Start < intervals[b].Start
        }
        return intervals[a].End < intervals[b].End
    })
    var vacantIdx int
    var roomCnt int = 1
    for i := 1; i < len(intervals); i++ {
        if intervals[i].Start < intervals[vacantIdx].End {
            roomCnt++
        } else {
            vacantIdx++
        }
    }

    return roomCnt
}
```

Explanation:

1. First sort the intervals based on their end time (Ascending & if the two intervals have same end time, sort them using their Start times (Ascending))
2. Store the index of the vacant room in vacantIdx.
3. If the next meeting conflicts with the meeting held in the current vacant room(Meeting which ends earliest), increment the room count.
4. If the next meeting doesn't conflict with the meeting held in the current vacant room(Meeting which ends earliest), just increment the vacant room index.

Question:
Is my approach to solve this problem correct? I can see in other forums that a heap is used to keep track of the ending time of all the meetings currently happening.

Comment: You need more complex test-example. I would randomly generate examples and make a brute force implementation (try all possibilities -> guaranteed to find the optimum) to compare the results with the algorithm in question.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the start and end times of each interval in a single array, noting whether each time is a start or end time. Where multiple intervals start or end at the same point, put end times before start times. This is O(n log n).

Parse your array of times, incrementing a counter every time you reach a start time, and decrementing it every time you reach an end time. The max of this counter along the array is the minimum number of meeting rooms you need.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in question finds a meeting with smallest end time before allocating a new meeting in it instead of finding the 'best fit'. It doesn't return the optimum result for the below input:

```
[[2, 8], [4 ,16], [10 ,20], [5 ,21], [15 ,21], [23 ,25], [3 ,27], [17, 29]]
```

The optimum result is 5, but the solution in question returns 6.

**Explanation of allocation strategy of the solution in question:**
[image]

**Output of ideal allocation:**
[image]

Based on the above findings, the solution in the internet(leetcode etc) which uses priority queue or two arrays sorted on start & end times are the best one.